# Maatwebsite, как сохранить файл в проект?

Tags: php, laravel

как сохранить файл в проект и далее отправить этот файл на почту, есть кто сталкивался с таким?

```
return Excel::download(new ArrayExport($data), 'array_data.xls');
    $test = (object)$offers->body->toArray();
```

пока что использую такой код, он сразу отправляет файл на загрузку

Comment: Открывай документацию и изучай, судя по всему тебе нужен `Excel::store`